# Paypal sandbox mode error

Tags: magento2, paypal, paypal-express, sandbox-mode

I configured both the merchant account on the paypal payment (**Paypal express**) method and in purchasing, but I get the error as

> Sorry, your bank wasn't able to verify your VISA x-4445 at this time.
>   Please choose another way to pay.

[image]

I have used the payment to accept only in India and there is no problem in that.
I have also configured the card `cvv` in [sandbox.paypal.com](http://sandbox.paypal.com) .

Though when I try to make a payment it shows the same error .

I have also created other sandbox personal accounts but it still shows the same error when I try to make the payment.

Is there is any way to resolve this?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Where did you get card number from? If I remember right you generate a card number when the sandbox account is created?

Comment: @DominicXigen I signed in at sandbox.payapal.com with the details of sandbox account given on developers.paypal.com and then for the generated card ,they told to updtae a cvv number which should be ushually given as 123.